# How to extend the timeout on lucene.net directory lock

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

[Directory lock error with Lucene.Net usage in an ASP.NET MVC site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241480/directory-lock-error-with-lucene-net-usage-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

Hi guys,

In the link above essentially is the issue I have.

However I am correctly disposing of the writer.

Problem is my main writer takes 20 mins due to the size of the data (200k + docs 25 Cols) and the slowness of the server.

So I have 2 writers one which does everything (all document on a 4 hour timer)

And one for when someone manually edits a column it removes a document and re adds it.

It is the second one that is throwing the timeout due to the fact that the first writer is still doing its thing taking forever. I would like to increase the timeout is this possible?

Cheers

Comment: Having a timeout of 20+ minutes sounds like a very bored user. Can't you process your content in small chunks, perhaps enough to just take a few seconds each, so that another writer may get some access to the index?

Comment: I was going to fire a thread that added it to the index so the user could keep on pedalin :). I think what we are leaning towards now is checking for the lock if it exists store the smaller modification to the index in a table that the larger modification checks apon completion. Would still be interested to know if you could extend the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the lock timeout by increasing [IndexWriter.WRITE_LOCK_TIMEOUT](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d1d/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_index_1_1_index_writer.html#a860de8d252b7555bf02d5adeaa90a2d2), or setting it to -1 to wait forever. There's also a [Lock.LOCK_POLL_INTERVAL](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/dd8/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_store_1_1_lock.html#a3e4d434af902a339175f3b8fc284d0d6) that states how often Lock.Obtain should attempt to retrieve the lock.